Convert a python non-tail recursive function adding sub-folders info to a loop
I wrote a function to get the total size and total files/subdirs of the entire disk or specific folder. The recursive function was very simple:
# Make the python dirSize function a non recursive one:
from pathlib import Path

obj = {}
def dirSize(dir: Path, size = 0, files = 0, dirs = 0):
    for sub_dir in dir.glob('*'):
        if sub_dir.is_dir():
            dirs += 1
            res_size, res_files, res_dirs = dirSize(sub_dir)
            size += res_size
            files += res_files
            dirs += res_dirs
        elif sub_dir.is_file():
            files += 1
            size += sub_dir.stat().st_size
    
    obj[dir.as_posix()] = {
        'size': size,
        'files': files,
        'dirs': dirs,
    }
    
    return size, files, dirs

dirSize(Path('~/Documents').expanduser())
#Line above is for tests. Final code should run in elevated cmd:
#dirSize(Path('C:/'))

with open(Path('~/Desktop/results.tsv').expanduser().as_posix(), 'w') as file:
    file.write('Directory\tBytes\tFiles\tDirs\n')
    for key in sorted(obj):
        dir = obj[key]
        file.write(key)
        file.write('\t')
        file.write(str(dir['size']))
        file.write('\t')
        file.write(str(dir['files']))
        file.write('\t')
        file.write(str(dir['dirs']))
        file.write('\n')

I tried to use AI to convert it to a non recursive function, but AI seems to ignore these lines are a bottom up sum, not a simple sum:
size += res_size
files += res_files
dirs += res_dirs

So I tried a stack loop, like in the Dijkstra algorithm, but it turns up that I couldn't find a simple solution to make the bottom up sum.
Alternatively I could add level/parent/child properties to the obj variable to make a bottom up sum after the queue processing. But this seems very cumbersome. Is there a simpler way to achieve this?



Replying questions asked below:

Why don't you just use os.walk?


It eliminates the recursion immediately, but doesn't help to do the bottom up sum - the generated report shows how many subdirs, disk space and files each directory has.


What's the problem with the recursive function?


There is no problem, it works to perfection! But my boss thinks not all developers can work with recursion, so he asked me for a non recursive version and I'm struggling to not make it too complicated.


why don't you just use os.walk?

also, important to note, tail recursion has no special status in CPython (there is no tail-call optimization)

What's the problem with the recursive function? Unless the directories are nearly 1000 levels deep, you shouldn't run into Python's recursion limit.

"But not all developers can work with recursion" << Why not?

I would answer that the only thing that could potentially be called too complicated with your function is that it does two things: (1) walk the directory tree (2) accumulate statistics; and then I would suggest splitting it into two functions, one that walks and one that takes the stats. But then the function that walks would just be os.walk and apparently you don't want to use that?

Based on answer from @awarrier99 I came up with this version that simplifies the logic a bit. I hope this helps future researchers:
def dirSizeIterative(dir: Path):
    dirs = [(dir, {'size': 0, 'files': 0, 'dirs': 0}, None)]
    i = 0

    #step 1, read dir/files info and add to array
    while i < len(dirs):
        dir, info, _ = dirs[i]
        i += 1
        
        for sub_dir in dir.glob('*'):
            if sub_dir.is_dir():
                info['dirs'] += 1
                dirs.append((sub_dir, {'size': 0, 'files': 0, 'dirs': 0}, info))
            elif sub_dir.is_file():
                info['files'] += 1
                info['size'] += sub_dir.stat().st_size

    #step 2, bottom up sum using the parent
    for _, info, parent in dirs[-1:0:-1]:
        parent['size'] += info['size']
        parent['files'] += info['files']
        parent['dirs'] += info['dirs']
    
    return {dir.as_posix(): info for dir, info, _ in dirs}


Your thought to use a stack approach was right - this can be achieved by creating a stack with tuple entries. Each tuple holds the subdirectory to process, as well as the name of the parent directory, so that the parent's stats can be updated accordingly. In order to update the parent's stats after all of its children's stats have been computed, we can add the parent entry back to the stack to be processed a second time. Here's an example iterative approach:
obj = {}

def dirSizeIterative(dir: Path):
    dir_stack = [(dir, 'root')]
    obj['root'] = {'size': 0, 'files': 0, 'dirs': 0}

    while dir_stack:
        sub_dir, parent_dir_name = dir_stack.pop(0)
        parent_info = obj[parent_dir_name]

        if sub_dir.is_dir():
            # if this exists, then we are processing this dir for the second time, after children have all been computed
            if sub_info := obj.get(sub_dir.as_posix()):
                parent_info['size'] += sub_info['size']
                parent_info['files'] += sub_info['files']
                parent_info['dirs'] += sub_info['dirs']

                continue

            sub_info = {'size': 0, 'files': 0, 'dirs': 0}
            obj[sub_dir.as_posix()] = sub_info

            parent_info['dirs'] += 1

            # add this dir back to the stack for processing after children have been computed
            dir_stack.insert(0, (sub_dir, parent_dir_name))

            for child in sub_dir.glob('*'):
                dir_stack.insert(0, (child, sub_dir.as_posix()))
        elif sub_dir.is_file():
            parent_info['files'] += 1
            parent_info['size'] += sub_dir.stat().st_size

    del obj['root']

dirSizeIterative(Path('~/Documents').expanduser())


I tested your function is working fine! This is what I really needed, you helped a lot. The trick I couldn't find was using the temporary "root" to start the interaction using the queue.

Please check my answer bellow. The stack approach like in Dijkstra’s is not the simplest solution, but just creating the structure by walking down the directory tree. The iterative version is superior than the recursive one. Thank you again!


But not all developers can work with recursion

Counterpoint: Maybe all developers can work with recursion, but your recursive function is a bit too complex because:

it does three things at the same time: walk recursively the subdirectories, update a global dict, and return a triplet;
it makes a hard-to-understand use of default arguments;
it relies on a global dict;
its return value, the triplet, is not something that the caller expects to get, since the caller is only interested in the dict

I suggest splitting the code into two functions:

a very straightforward recursive walking function;
a non-recursive function that creates and fills a dict, and returns this dict, and doesn't return a triplet.

Something like this:
from collections import defaultdict

def walk(dir: Path):
    '''
    Walk directory recursively and yield (node, parent_name) pairs
    '''
    for sub_dir in dir.glob('*'):
        if sub_dir.is_dir():
            yield from walk(sub_dir)
        yield (sub_dir, dir.as_posix())

def dirSize(dir: Path):
    obj = defaultdict(lambda (): {'size': 0, 'files': 0, 'dirs': 0})
    for (node, parent_name) in walk(dir):
        size, files = (node.stat().st_size, 1) if node.is_file() else (0, 0)
        dirs = 1 if node.is_dir() else 0
        node_dict = obj[node.as_posix()]
        parent_dict = obj[parent_name]
        for d in (node_dict, parent_dict):
            d['size'] += size
            d['files'] += files
            d['dirs'] += dirs
    return obj


This is not what was asked, but is actually very helpful because simplifies the function a lot.
